# On a code of serial port communication

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have come across the [code on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9123280/2151545). It is an answer to the question with C# tag, but I couldn't understand some parts:

```
using System.Port.IO; ( ? System.IO.Ports)

System.Windows.Timers.Timer serialTimer; (There is no system.windows.timers ?)

serialPort1.DataReceived+=Tab Enter (What's the function of tab and enter here?)

serialPort1.Interval =100; ?
```

Would you please help me in understanding them?

Comment: Read the other replies in that thread. Or better yet, find a working example and work from that. That poster's use of a timer is dubious at best - you should not need one for plain serial comms.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Read and Write from the Serial Port in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243070/how-to-read-and-write-from-the-serial-port-in-c-sharp)

Comment: My question is not about to communicate with a serial port. The link I gave is an answer, not a topic. I am trying to understand what kind of code it is on the link, not to learn how to communicate with a port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The link I gave is an answer, not a topic. I am trying to understand what kind of code it is on the link, not to learn how to communicate with a port.

This code was typed by someone without compiling it, and it's full of syntactical and conceptual errors. I'll try to address the lines in your question:

> ```
> using System.Port.IO; ( ? System.IO.Ports)
> ```

Yes, he probably meant to type [`System.IO.Ports`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

> ```
> System.Windows.Timers.Timer serialTimer; (There is no system.windows.timers ?)
> ```

No, there isn't. He either meant a [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) or a [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

> ```
> serialPort1.DataReceived+=Tab Enter
> ```
>
> (What's the function of tab and enter here?)

Those commands (though I usually <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>) write an empty event handler for you, like:

```
void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

But that is makes little sense here, as his code already shows an event handler for that, so that line should actually read:

```
serialPort1.DataReceived += serialPort1_DataReceived;
```

---

> ```
> serialPort1.Interval =100; ?
> ```

Typo again, he probably meant to set the timer's interval through `serialTimer.Interval`.

So I think the lesson here is: always assume the worst when you're copypasting someone's code off the web.

Comment: Thank you. It's very kind of you.